# Partition by unique key, set flag with case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to split out a set of data by the policy no and set a flag based on a set of conditions and i'm having trouble with the logic.

Data as follows:

```
Policy_no, role  
1 , 'Owner'  
1 , 'Beneficiary'  
1 , 'Beneficiary'
2 , 'Owner'
2 , 'Life assured'
3 , 'Life assured'
```

So i'm trying to split the data by policy_no, so that if an owner is present, the flag gets set to '1', however if no owner is present, then flag is set if life_assured is present, however flag cannot be 'y' for both owner and life_assured.

IE:

```
Policy_no, role, flag  
1 , 'Owner'          ,1  
1 , 'Beneficiary'    ,0  
1 , 'Beneficiary'    ,0
2 , 'Owner'          ,1
2 , 'Life assured 1' ,0
3 , 'Life assured 1' ,1
3 , 'Life assured 2' ,1 
4 , 'Beneficiary'    ,0
```

I set the title to partition by unique key because that's what i've been attemping, but currently to no avail. Am open to new ideas however.

EDIT: Apologies, this is for oracle dbms.
edit 2 : Added more data to show off the different possibilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**USING Oracle**

```
SELECT Policy_no,
   role,
   CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN
         1
   ELSE
         0
   END AS FLAG
FROM
  (
   SELECT Policy_no,
          role,
          Row_Number() Over (Partition BY Policy_no Order BY Policy_no) AS RN 
    FROM table1
  )
```

**DEMO For Oracle**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8561a/20

**USING MYSQL**

```
SELECT Policy_no
     , role
     , FLAG  
FROM
(
  SELECT Policy_no
         , role
         , CASE WHEN @Policy_no != T.Policy_no 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS FLAG
          ,@Policy_no := T.Policy_no AS VarPolicy_no
    FROM   Table1 AS T,(SELECT @Row :=null,@Policy_no := -1) AS R
)AS T1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Policy_no   role           FLAG
1           Owner           1
1           Beneficiary     0
1           Beneficiary     0
2           Owner           1
3           Life assured    1
```

**Demo For MYSQL**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/800a9/3

Comment: This doesn't work in my version of toad for some reason. It doesn't like the keyword Row

Comment: Can't you specify dbms for your first query as well?

Comment: Edited my initial post, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Check 1st Answer It will Work @EkulSregor

Comment: This does work but it doesn't set the ones outside of the case to 0. For instance if a beneficiary is the first row in a policy, this gets set as the owner, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I add some data in my demo to test all the rules:

```
  SELECT Policy_no
         , role
         , IIF(CASE
                   WHEN role = 'owner' THEN 1
                   WHEN role = 'Life assured' THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END = 1
                 AND SUM(CASE
                           WHEN role = 'owner' THEN 1
                           WHEN role = 'Life assured' THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                         END)
                       OVER (
                         Partition BY Policy_no ) < 2, 1, IIF(role = 'owner', 1, 0)) flag
    FROM   cte
    ORDER  BY Policy_no
```

SQL Server Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/11009

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.